# How do I remove all Gnome Environments I had added?

Tags: gnome, 12.10, gnome-classic

I had installed the Gnome DE...but it seemed quite laggy and thus removed it...
Also removed the Gnome-PPA n the DE package,etc...but in the log in menu,i still see "Gnome Classic" and "Gnome Classic (no Effects)" how do I remove them too?

Comment: This is not working... when I enter the line "sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3" I get back the following... Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: gnome3-team gnome3
Warning: Could not find package list for PPA: gnome3-team gnome3 I know it's there... I can still see the package listed in my Synaptic Package Manager app.

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands in order

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Restart your PC